# $expr' operator not supported in AWS documentdb - Any alternative to $exp

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

We are trying to migrate Mongo 4.4 version to Document DB 3.6 - 4 version. While checking for compaitability we saw  '$expr' operator not supported. Is there any alternative to this in AWS Documentdb?

Two sample statement :

```
RARELD.quoteLineItems.find({'$expr': {'$ne': ['$opportunityID', '$opportunityID']}}, {})  // ['$expr']
```

```
RARE2D.rareQuotes.aggregate([{'$match': {'lob': 'Medical', 'errors.errorList': {'$exists': True}, '$expr': {'$gte': [{'$size': '$errors.errorList'}, 3]}}}, {'$skip': 0}, {'$group': {'_id': 1, 'n': {'$sum': 1}}}])  // ['$expr']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative to `$expr` as this is the only operator that allow's you to use aggregation operators within the query language, specifically when it comes to the simple queries (aka `find`).

When you're using an aggregation you can always find a workaround, it just might be less efficient.

Specifically with your aggregation example you can just write

```
'$expr': {'$gte': [{'$size': '$errors.errorList'}, 3]}}
```

as

```
"errors.errorList.2": {"$exists": True}
```

Comment: Thank you for editing my question. I will try to format the question properly next time. Thanks for you quick suggestion, I will look to code around this as suggested.